# ERR_CACHE_MISS after migrating server?

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome

I have a LAMP based server, with php as the main language. I recently migrated my server to a new server with a better processor and RAM. 
My website was being hosted by the old server for an year.
When my website got migrated today, the first thing i saw was a

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS https://scriptname.php
```

This error never appeared on the older server. I have tested it on 20 machines with chrome, and i get this error frequently on all pages. What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have the AdBlock extension installed? Disabled it and check this again.

Comment: nope.. no extension at all

Comment: Do you have the same issue when accessing the site with another browser?

Comment: no only chrome. works in firefox and safari

Comment: Then disable the extensions you have one at a time and find the culprit and knock it off

Comment: I think this is a bug in the latest version of Chrome. For me it suddenly popped up about one week ago (and I did not migrate my server). There is an issue report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599)